# How can i add image in system_alert_window flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, system-alert-window

I am using system_alert_window flutter package and want to add user image in body but not able to achieve this. please help.

Comment: The package you are using does not support the image in System Alert Window

Answer (score -3):

You can use Dialog instead of alert window, in Dialog you can customise as your need.

```
 Dialog customDialog = Dialog(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)), 
  child: Container(
    height: 300.0,
    width: 300.0,
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
       //Cutomise your widget with Image and Text
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

To show the Dialog

```
showDialog(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) => customDialog);
```